# CSS Carrossel dentro de outra imagem

Tags: html, css

Preciso fazer um carrossel/slideshow de imagens só que ele acontece dentro de outra imagem.
Exemplo:

Tenho essa imagem do notebook em png, o slideshow deve aconecer dentro da tela dele. No entanto, controles como setas e "bolinhas" p/ indicar qual imagem está sendo apresentada devem ficar fora do notebook.

[image: notebook png]

Sou bem novato nisso, alguém sabe se tem como fazer isso e pode me mostrar um caminho?

EDIT: 
Além de tudo meus slides estão com problema.. segue exemplo no js fiddle do que eu tenho até agora no jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/do9jLvk6/

Comment: Você pode tentar aplicar o carrossel normalmente, diminuir se necessário o container central do carrossel e jogar essa imagem com fundo transparente, na frente do carrossel. Sendo assim, o carrosel seria padrão mas com a imagem na frente ...

Comment: Vou tentar! para isso utilizo aquela propriedade z-index no meu css?

Comment: Isso mesmo, se conseguir postar algum código de fácil reprodução, para podermos testar por fora será bem útil.

Comment: @Bruno editei a pergunta com o código que fiz até agora.. deu problema tb , mas se quiser dar uma olhada

Comment: O tamanho da imagem do notebook é estática? Se for, qual seria o tamanho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja funcionando no Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/do9jLvk6/2/

O que fiz foi criar uma div `#notebook` que será o container do slider e coloquei a imagem do notebook como background dessa div.

Em seguida defini as dimensões e posicionei o a div do slider no centro, dentro do monitor do notebook.

Modifiquei o posicionamento das setas e das "bolinhas" para que ficassem fora.

Bom, tudo isso vai depender muito do tamanho que vc quer a imagem do notebook. Se for aumentar ou diminuir, basta fazer os devidos ajustes.

Comment: Muito legal, obrigado! Só tem um problema, quando abro no navegador, as imagens aparecem uma em cima da outra, só se escondem e mostram apenas o que deveria ser mostrado após o primeiro clique numa das setas ou bolinhas.. tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Troque a linha `showSlides(slideIndex);` por `$(function(){showSlides(slideIndex);});`

Comment: Pode me explicar qual é a diferença entre essas linhas? Infelizmente não deu certo... continua igual

Comment: A primeira linha é executada antes do carregamento da página, a segunda após. O `showSlides(slideIndex);` deve ser chamado quando todos os elementos forem carregados. Faça o seguinte, coloque todo o script no final do HTML, antes da tag </body>.

Comment: Entendi! Agora funcionou! Muito obrigado mesmo, ajudou bastante